# solution of system of coupled partial differential equations

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, automotive-engineering

I have following system of coupled Partial differential equations.
How can I solve the system by Maple?
\begin{align}   m_1\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial t^2}+A_1\frac{\partial ^4u_1(x,t)}{\partial x^4}+k(u_1-u_2)=F_1(t) \delta(x-x_1),  \end{align}
\begin{align}    m_2\frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial t^2}-A_2\frac{\partial ^2u_2(x,t)}{\partial x^2}+k(u_2-u_1)=F_2(t)\delta(x-x_2).  \end{align}

In here,  $A_i, m_i, x_i$ and $k$ are constants where $i=1,2$ and $\delta$ is Dirac Delta function.
**Boundary conditions:**

$u_1(0,t)=\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x^2}(0,t)=u_1(l,t)=\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x^2}(l,t)=0$,

$u_2(0,t)=u_2(l,t)=0$

**Initial conditions:**

$u_i(x,0)=w_{i0}(x),$

$\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x}(x,0)=y_{i0}(x)$ for $i=1,2.$

Since $F_1(t)$ and $F_2(t)$ are unspecified (ungiven) functions, solutions $u_1,u_2$ which we seek will be depended on  $F_1(t)$ and $F_2(t)$.

**Maple Code:**

```
PDE1:=m1*diff(u1(x,t),t$2)+A1*diff(u1(x,t),x$4)+k*(u1(x,t)-u2(x,t))=F1(t)*delta(x-x1);
PDE2:=m2*diff(u2(x,t),t$2)-A2*diff(u2(x,t),x$2)+k*(u2(x,t)-u1(x,t))=F2(t)*delta(x-x2);
```

Comment: How have you programmed them in Maple so far?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with engineering, and should probably be at [Math.SE].